# Detecting AJAX requests in vanilla NodeJS without JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

What is the best method for going about differentiating AJAX requests and other browser HTTP requests? I'm using vanilla NodeJS with AtomicJS as the AJAX library. It does not seem to set the 'X-Requested-With' header, which I read was used by JQuery to indicate AJAX requests. Should I switch to a library that does? Is there another way to detect AJAX requests? Should I just attempt to set the header manually, and are there any potential issues involved in doing so?

Comment: Why not just pass some data in the ajax request, and check if it's there, you shouldn't really need more

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to tell the difference (short of you explicitly setting a header or other indicator on all of your own requests). More importantly, it should not really matter how the request was sent.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly state that the request was coming from an Ajax request in the header or in the body of the request, but likely the better way to do this would be to have a separate endpoint on the server for an ajax request.

For instance your uri for an non ajax request might be

```
http://myserver.com/non-ajax-uri
```

and then you could have another endpoint at

```
http://myserver.com/ajax-uri
```

If most of the behavior is shared between the two endpoints simply encapsulate it in another function that both of the end points share.

Comment: So, say I have an Ajax request whose role is to grab some JSON data from the server and pass it to a script client-side. If I use a separate endpoint, how can I prevent users from just navigating to http://myserver.com/ajax-uri and seeing a bunch of raw data?

Comment: @S.Liu I assume you already have some authorization/authentication mechanism in place, and well you cannot specifically prohibit an authorized user for direct accessing the uri, you can effectively hide it by not creating a direct link to the uri from the application. There shouldn't be any security issues if the user is already authorized so unless they want to see the data in an ugly format, there shouldn't be a concern.